# Searching/selecting query in cache

Tags: caching, redis

I have been using cache for a long time. We store data against some key and fetch it from cache whenever required. I know that StackOverflow and many other sites heavily rely on cache. My question is do they always use key-value mechanism for caching or do they form some sql like query within a cache? For instance, I want to view last week report. This report's content will vary each day. Do i need to store different reports against each day (where day as a key) or can I get this result from forming some query that aggregate result across different key? Does any caching product (like redis) provide this functionality?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Cache is always done as a key-value hash table. This is how it stays so fast. If you're doing querying then you're not doing cache.

What you may be trying to ask is... you could have in your database a table that contains agregated report data. And you could query against that pre-calculated table.

Comment: Redis does have some other data types, other than just a string value. It has lists and ranges and things like that. But I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: We need to use cache in reporting. Reports can be seen for today, last week, last month etc. So, same data-set is part of different reports. Datasets are flowing per seconds. One dataset belongs to a product and reports are also viewed per product. Can any caching solution help in this scenerio?

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for cache (e.g. memcached ) being fast is its simplicity of data access and querying protocol.
The more functionality you add, more tradeoff you will have to do on the efficiency part. A full fledged SQL engine in a "caching" database is not a good design. Though you can utilize a data structures oriented database like Redis to design your cache data to suit your querying needs. For example: one set or one hash for each date.

A step further, you can use databases like MongoDb , or memsql which are pretty fast and have rich querying support.So an aggregation report once a while won't be an issue.
However, as a design decision, you will have to accept that their caching throughput will not be as much as memcached or redis.